# Is there a method to vibrate for less than 1 millisecond on Android?

Tags: java, android

Vibrate.vibrate takes a long value so the minimum is 1 millisecond. Is there a native interface or something I can poke at to get shorter durations?

Comment: No - Even if there was the hardware is not physically capable of being that precise. (Specifying 1ms won't even be 1ms.)

Comment: By "physically capable of" I only mean being able to supply voltage to the inductor, not actually produce vibration effect. I have an LG G watch and I thought it would be fun to turn the vibrator into a mini-beeper/speaker if I could hit it with a 10kHz sampling rate. Perhaps there's a way to hardware poke it in C?

Comment: for what specifically do you want vibrate your device less than 1 ms?

Comment: to hack an Android Wear watch and use the vibrator as a low-volume beeper and generate square waves at arbitrary audible frequencies, since it doesn't have a built-in speaker. yes, it's hack-ish, but it would be cool.

Answer (score 1):

*Personally, I doubt that the hardware is as precise as its api makes it out to be (to make apis more future-proof and more stable, they're often given capabilities and precision that haven't been implemented in hardware yet).*

But yes, there is a [more native Android api](http://www2.immersion.com/developers/index.php?option=com_wrapper&view=wrapper&Itemid=765) that measures haptic feedback in not only milliseconds, but also **microseconds**.

The name of the company is called [Immersion](http://immersion.com/). They make the OEM vibration motors/actuators for ~70% of Android phones (Samsung's phones and a bunch of other manufacturers). I don't know what marketshare they have on watches, but I wouldn't be surprised if they dominated there too.

If you'd like to try out one of their demo apps (on an Android phone/tablet, I don't know if they have one for watches yet). It's [available here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.immersion.EffectPreview) on the Google Play Store (it should also work on non-Immersion Android devices, like HTC devices, although it won't be as precise on those).